# One activitiy with different backgrounds in android

Tags: android, button, layout, background

I am trying to create an android app. I have two buttons next and back in my android app. I want when i click on next button its open same activity with different background. Next time i again click next new background image. And on press on `back` button its show previous image. And if no previous image its shows menu on press. Similarly if background with last image its hide next `button`. I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.back)
        {
            startActivty(new Intent(this,));
        }
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.next)
        {
            startActivity(newIntent(this,));
        }               
    }
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ques"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/back2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/back2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ques"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In layout as you can see i am using image back for background. I want when i click next new background image then next and so on.

But i dont know how to start same activity with differene backgroud.

Comment: post your layout file too

Comment: use an image array and set your layout background eachtime. otherwise use Random class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

**Global:**

```
int[] backgrounds = new int[]{ images in drawable as int array };   
int count = 0;
Button back,next;
RelativeLayout img_backn_lay;
```

**JAVA:**

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_backn_lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_lay);
    img_backn_lay.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[count]);
    count += 1;
```

**ClickListener:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.next)
    {
        if(backgrounds.length != count){
            img_backn_lay.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[count]);
            count += 1; 
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.back)
    {
        if(count != 0){
            img_backn_lay.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[count]);
            count -= 1; 
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }    
}
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: i want to use background using setContentView.

Comment: @JohnR is there any error? post that error. And also post your whole code.

Comment: And as you can see in xml i dont have id of relative layout. Can i use layoutname..setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[count]);?

Comment: you want i give relative layout id **main_lay** in above xml?

Comment: @JohnR yes then only we can set the background image programmatically.

Comment: and i have to delete background attribute in xml in question?

Comment: @JohnR no problem with that. Any way delete that.

Comment: @JohnR did you get the result.

Comment: I need your little more help.

Comment: Like in background array **int[] backgrounds = new int[]{ images in drawable as int array };** I am writing items as R.drawable.image1. If I want take item as string then how yo write?

Comment: @JohnR use String[] aa = new String[]{"",""}; like that.

Comment: ok thank you. please see this link if you like to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178571/justify-text-in-textview/21178669?noredirect=1#comment31885886_21178669

Answer (score 1):

Don't start new Activity just change the background:

Keep an array of background resources in your activity like:

```
int[] backgroundResId;
```

and one int variable to store current background index:

```
int currentIndex=0;
```

now inside your onCreate initialize this array with resource id's of all the backgrounds drawables:

```
backgroundResId=new int[]{R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c};
changeBackground()
```

create function changeBackground in activity:

```
private void changeBackground(){
     findViewById(R.id.root_layout).setBackgroundResource(backgroundResId[currentIndex]);
}
```

Now onClick of next button increase currentIndex:

```
currentIndex++;
if(current<=backgroundResId.length){
     changeBackground();
}else{
    // setVisibility of next button to invisible
}
```

onBackButton Click

```
currentIndex--;
if(current>=0){
     changeBackground();
     //// setVisibility of next button to visible
}else{
  //show menu
}
```

Comment: In changeBackground() you are using id resource but i want to set background in layout.

Comment: i want to use background using setContentView.

Comment: @JohnR , If you want to use setContentView to change Background, you have to add as many layout files with different images. however that is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Make an images array and post your data to the next activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("background", imageIdInTheImageArray);
    startActivity(intent);

    //finish();
```

and in your onCreate function :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        int background = b.getInt("background");
        //set your background
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an **ImageView** in your xml file.

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

you can change background using this

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```