# justify text in textview not working properly

Tags: android, github, textview

I am taking reference from  [TextJustify-Android](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android). I am implementing **option 2** in above link. When I run my app on emulator text appears one word in one line, next word in next line and so on. I dont know whats wrong in my code. Please help me. Thanks.

Activity class code-

```
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener()
        {           
            boolean isJustified = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() 
            {
                if(!isJustified)
                {
                    TextJustifyUtils.run(textView1,0);
                    isJustified = true;
                }

                return true;
            }

        });
```

Xml code-

```
 <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="8"
       android:gravity="center">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:text="@string/his"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

       </LinearLayout>
```

And I am implementing `TextJustifyUtils` class in my app as suggested in above link.

I have made one change In that link given `TextJustifyUtils.run(textView1);` and In my code eclipse suggest me to change in `TextJustifyUtils.run(textView1,0);`. Is anything wrong with this?

Update:

In `TextJustifyUtils` I change `public static void justify(TextView textView)` into `public static void run(TextView textView)` as commented by the author there and `TextJustifyUtils.run(textView1,0);` into `TextJustifyUtils.run(textView1);` in Activity class. But the output is same as I type in my `textView` i.e text without justification.

Comment: But why to delete this question you know any other way to justify using textview not webview.

Comment: ok then how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some one following the above link to justify text please choose option 1. Its work fine. And if you have any problem. Ask from author. I think he always happy to help you nice guy. As he helps me so much. And option 1 working with minor changes.