# App stop working

Tags: android, textview, logcat, justify

First I am trying [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202560/justify-text-in-textview-not-working-properly). And I am stuck then I ask question But no one gives any answer. Then I try another way suggested by @sayed.jalil in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178571/justify-text-in-textview). But my app stop working. If someone provide answer for first link Really appriciated. And if someone like to answer the alternative I've tried according to @sayed.jalil answer. For that my code below-

Xml code-

```
<com.info.abc.JustifiedTextView  
android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Activity code-

```
JustifiedTextView txtViewEx = (JustifiedTextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
txtViewEx.setText("some text");
```

JustifiedTextView.java -

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class JustifiedTextView extends WebView {

    private String core = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;color:rgba(%s);font-size:%dpx;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;'>%s</body></html>";
    private String textColor = "0,0,0,255";
    private String text = "";
    private int textSize = 12;
    private int backgroundColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;

    public JustifiedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        });

    }

    public void setText(String s) {
        this.text = s;
        // this.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        reloadData();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void reloadData() {

        // loadData(...) has a bug showing utf-8 correctly. That's why we need
        // to set it first.
        this.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        this.loadData(String.format(core, textColor, textSize, text),
            "text/html", "utf-8");

        // set WebView's background color *after* data was loaded.
        super.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        // Hardware rendering breaks background color to work as expected.
        // Need to use software renderer in that case.
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            this.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int hex) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(hex);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(0, 2), 16);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(2, 4), 16);
        int g = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(4, 6), 16);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(6, 8), 16);
        textColor = String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d", r, g, b, a);
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int hex) {
        backgroundColor = hex;
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        reloadData();
    }

}
```

Logcat-

```
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): Process: com.info.abc, PID: 1482
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.info.abc/com.info.abc.History}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.info.abc.JustifiedTextView
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.info.abc.JustifiedTextView
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.info.abc.History.onCreate(History.java:19)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     ... 11 more
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: can you post the code for the JustifiedTextView?

Comment: Please provide comment for every downvote so that I know whats wrong in my question. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Justify text in textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178571/justify-text-in-textview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
01-19 10:43:19.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):
     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
```

You are not providing all of the constructors required for a custom view.
Specifically, add this constructor.  Read the documentation and tutorials for how to use the attribute set:

```
public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){   
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
}
```

Comment: And Can I set different text sizes for different screen sizes in different xml for textview?

Comment: Why would you want different text sizes? The system takes care of that when you specify the dp value. If you really want different text sizes you can by creating different xml layouts for different device configurations (i.e. using the res/layout-swdp600 folder).