# Justify text in Tetview

Tags: android, textview

Try to justify text but i am not able to do that i want to start text start an end at equal margin from both left and right side. How to do that?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/about_us"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't support justified text yet.

You can use an external library to do your work.

I recommend this:

https://github.com/nikoo28/justify-textview-android

Answer (score 0):

First of all Android do not support full justification, but if you want to justify your text try this way

Just add to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
}
```

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**OR**

Try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JustifiedTextView mJTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mJTv=(JustifiedTextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_jtv_text);
        mJTv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.test));
        mJTv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
        mJTv.setLineSpacing(15);
        mJTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        mJTv.setAlignment(Align.LEFT);
        mJTv.setTypeFace(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/naskh_bold.ttf"));

    }
}
```

XML

```
<ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_jtv_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="25dp"
        xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir"
        noghteh:text="@string/hello_world"
        noghteh:textColor="@color/text"
        noghteh:textSize="18sp"
       >
    </ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView>
```

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

Comment: use it in oncreateview

Comment: JustifiedTextView  do not resolve this symbol ? i add this dependency too compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'

Comment: did you try to import library? please check complete example in link

Comment: did you create seperate class for justifytextview which extend Textview? or else try it with HTML
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178571/justify-text-in-textview

Comment: not i made a xml file where i ue textview and use that layout in fragment.but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Justify text in textview android.

```
String dis="You can write your content here";

String text_string="<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\">"+dis+"<body><html>";

TextView text=setText(fromHtml(text_string));
```