# Why setMovementMethod() breaks text justification in TextView?

Tags: android, text, textview, justify

I have a `TextView` with these attributes:

```
android:maxLines = "10"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

By using above attributes, `textView` displays text justified:

[image]

But when I set *movement method* for `textView` like below, `justification` breaks:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

[image]

How can I set a `TextView` to be `scrollable` and display its text `justified`?

*Note*: I have to use `TextView` and cannot use any other `View` or `CustomView`.

Comment: can you post some screenshots

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047930/7319704

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Thank you, but I do not want to use a CustomView.

Comment: @PembaTamang Please see the question again.

Comment: there is also an answer that uses html tags to justify text. The accepted answer, try that

Comment: @PembaTamang I have to use `TextView`.

Comment: hey @hasanghaforian if you want I can work on your code if you let me clone it... kinda free and bored here

Comment: reply quick....

Comment: Please share the code for adding justify to TextView

Comment: Any solution for this  @hasanghaforian

Comment: @rams I'm sorry. No solution.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Any solution for this issue yet?

Comment: I was facing the same problem and found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660290/justificationmode-with-linkmovementmethod-make-text-cut-off